# RCurl dumps core with option ftpupload=TRUE

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I attempt to ftp-uplad a small file to an ftp server which I *must* use with "active" ftp (`curl -P` option), my R Session dumps core. Any idea what's happening here, and which options I must pass to `RCurl::ftpUpload()`?

```
.opts <- list("verbose" = TRUE, "ftp.use.epsv" = FALSE, 
    "ftp.use.eprt" = TRUE, "connecttimeout" = 3, ftpport=TRUE)
myfile <- "path/myfile.json"
file.exists(myfile)   # returns  TRUE

cmd <- sprintf("ftp://%s:%s@myserver.de/mytargetdir/%s", 
   Sys.getenv("R__ftpuser"), Sys.getenv("R__ftppw"), 
   basename(myfile))
ftpUpload(myfile, cmd, .opts=.opts)
```

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x1, cause 'memory not mapped'

```
Traceback:
 1: curlPerform(url = to, upload = TRUE, readfunction = uploadFunctionHandler(file,     asText), ..., curl = curl)
 2: ftpUpload(myfile, cmd, .opts = .opts)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

my R Session:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)  for linux
RCurl version 1.95-4.11
```

The command line call works :

`curl -P - myfile ftp://... -T --disable-eprt #uploads the file`

my curl:

```
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

When I leave the  `ftpport=TRUE` option out, there is a timeout.

This also happens with `R --vanilla`

Comment: Be sure you're using the most recent version of RCurl; I have `packageVersion("RCurl")` returns `[1] '1.95.4.11'` for me. Likely this requires a fix from the maintainer, so you should reach out to them `maintainer("RCurl")` preferably with a fully reproducible example. Does the [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/package=curl) package offer similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

the option value must be `"-"` and not `TRUE`.

```
.opts <- list("verbose" = TRUE, "ftp.use.epsv" = FALSE, "ftpport" = "-",
              "ftp.use.eprt" = TRUE, "connecttimeout" = 3)
ftpUpload(myfile, cmd, .opts=.opts)
```

Then the output will look like this:

```
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for myfile.json
* Preparing for accepting server on data port
* Checking for server connect
* Ready to accept data connection from server
* Connection accepted from server
* Remembering we are in dir "some/dir/"
< 226 Transfer complete
* Connection #0 to host myserver.de left intact
```

The behaviour is documented here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FTPPORT.html:

> The PORT instruction tells the remote server to connect to our
>   specified IP address. The string may be a plain IP address, a host
>   name, a network interface name (under Unix) or **just a '-' symbol** to
>   let the library use your system's default IP address.

(emphasis mine)